# How to add styles to a plugin via functions.php

Tags: php, css, wordpress, plugins

The question title is self explanatory but, here it goes something else:

I need to add a small amount of `CSS` rules to style a plugin but I need to do it in my `Wordpress` `functions.php` to avoid messing around with core files of that same plugin.

Is this possible, how?

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/255405/functions-php-inject-inline-css

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to "add style to the plugin," as a correctly configured WordPress installation will allow you to override the plugin CSS easily without interfacing with the plugin at all.

You should be using a [WordPress Child Theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/). You can add your CSS to the end of the child them `style.css` file.

You can also include CSS through theme settings in some themes. Search for "Custom CSS [YourThemeName].

Or, you can choose [one of many plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/Custom+CSS/) that will permit you to configure custom CSS as well.

Finally, you could use [one of many different approaches](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/) for including style with PHP.

I often use [wp_add_inline_style](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_style/) for simple, brief CSS inclusions:

```
function add_some_custom_style(){
 ob_start(); 
 ?>
.someclass { 
  somestyle: style; 
}
 <?php
 $style = ob_get_clean();
 if (! wp_style_is('some-custom-style-handle', 'enqueued')) {
  wp_register_style('some-custom-style-handle', false );
  wp_enqueue_style('some-custom-style-handle');
  wp_add_inline_style('some-custom-style-handle', $style);
 }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'add_some_custom_style');
```

Comment: None of these options pass styles to the elements in my plugin

Comment: All of these options are viable strategies. Perhaps you could update your question with example HTML output from your plugin and the CSS that you're hoping to implement?